# Apache2 sends continuous max bandwidth data upon page reload

Tags: apache-2.2

An apache2 server on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.1 (all updates installed) has a major problem, I've pulled so much hair out that I don't have much left.

Any time a page is loaded into a browser from the server, one of two things happens, depending on what browser is used to connect:

**Firefox**:  The page is loaded correctly, then a continuous stream of data is sent from the server.  It continues until Firefox is killed.  The internet connection into my office is maxed out until I kill the browser.

IE9/10, Chrome: The page is loaded correctly.  Everything is fine unless I reload the page.  At that point the page loads correctly but the continuous data stream starts and continues until the browser is killed.

This happens no matter what kind of page is loaded.  Even something as simple as the following will cause it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The same thing happens with a fresh install of Firefox on a *different machine* so I don't think any of the browsers are at fault.  Both of the machines I've tested on are running Win8.  The only thing these two client boxes have in common is an ADSL router.  Later today I'll check with an XP client to eliminate the possibility of a Win8 related issue.

This behaviour is only seen on pages loaded from the server in question.

There isn't anything in the apache errorlog or in syslog that's relevant.

I've compared apache2.conf with another server that does not exhibit this behaviour.  Nothing is different.  There are a number of apache2 modules running on the affected server.  I haven't yet compared the module config files but will begin to do so now.

Any suggestions to help troubleshoot are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some problem with gzip/deflate compression?
But i would start by installing a packet capturer on the client machine (like wireshark ), and take a look at the incoming flow.

Answer (score 0):

Using a copy of Microsoft Network analyzer, I found that there were huge bursts of packets loading favicon.ico

When I looked at the location of favicon.ico I found a 145 megabyte file.

As soon as I removed the file the problem stopped.

I saved the huge favicon file in another location, now I have to figure out where it came from or what happened to cause it to be so large.

I'm not inclined to suspect this is a hacked server symptom.  More likely that I did something to cause it.  I don't know if I can trace the cause back but I'll try.

Comment: Check the favicon file type, first 1kbyte data, maybe if you know the content you can find out how it happened.

Comment: It contained a bunch of source code from our site.  I'm inclined to think that either I fat-fingered some operation or else some backup task ran amok.